# could not find resouce in mybatis

Tags: java, maven, mybatis

I'm using maven + mybatis on win10.

File structure is as follows:

```
├─src
│  ├─main
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  └─com
│  │  │      └─company
│  │  │          └─app
│  │  │             └─mybatisInsert.java
│  │  │              ─SqlMapConfig.xml
│  │  │              ─Student.java
│  │  │              ─Student.xml
│  │  └─resources
│  └─test
│      └─java
└─target
```

So you can see, `SqlMapConfig.xml` is at the same directory as `mybatisInsert`. `mybatisInsert` is the file which contains the main class. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
package main.java.com.company.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;

public class mybatisInsert {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");
    }

}
```

It doesn't work, I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not find resource SqlMapConfig.xml
        at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:114)
        at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:100)
        at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsReader(Resources.java:160)
        at main.java.com.cisco.ng.mybatisInsert.main(mybatisInsert.java:15)
```

I tried to chanage the path to the following, none of them worked.

How can I make it work?

Comment: try to put the XML files into resources and add a slash where you read it Resources.getResourceAsReader("/SqlMapConfig.xml");

Comment: only java files belong in src/main/java. Everything else should be placed in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big thanks to @Jens, finally I solved the problem by putting `SqlMapConfig.xml` in the `resource` directory.

Comment: But why does it work ? Your previous xml files were also on a class file path, I would have thought if you had said com/company/app/SqlMapConfig.xml it should've worked. Anyways, I am struggling with this too. I feel external paths for these config files is alot less time consuming and un-necessary anger & frustration. myBatis classpath locations NOT WORKING. No framework has the maxim "Don't make me think"